# A simple one. Is this a folder, or a php/py file, with a hidden extension

Tags: php, html

So what does 9gag have for each of it's posts? A gag folder with thousands of single-file folders, or is it just a php (or py... I didn't check) file with a hidden extension?

Here is the link:

> http://9gag.com/gag/a7LQzWw

BTW, I didn't choose the post by it's hilariousness :) Just a random post :)

Oh, and if it's a single file, isn't it memory consuming to have separate files for every post? Thank you for any replies :)

Comment: What's hilarious in this?

Comment: That is just routing - the internal logic is up to their implementation, but of course it does not reflect their filesystem structure.

Comment: check out mod_rewrite to see what it does.http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/

Comment: +1 since -1 is not necessary for being curious. Can imagine that 'What have you tried?' is not really relevant here.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I quote myself: "BTW, I didn't choose the post by it's hilariousness :)" - I didn't search for a one having a funny pic... just a random one

Answer (score 3):

This is all assumption based off the URL and other sites that host large amounts of content in a similar fashion.

It's most likely an MVC (model, view, controller) web application, I can't tell what language. They'll be using some form of dispatching/routing (Apache's mod_rewrite for example) to get all requests through some common code.

9gag.com is the server. /gag/ is the 'controller', this controller has been coded to then know that the next part of the URL is the post/image ID. So it grabs the ID from the URL (or dispatcher already did this and passed the ID to the controller) and uses it to look up the content from a database (the model) and inserts it into a generic template (view).